# grep for one pattern but not for another pattern

Tags: grep, aix

A purely grep question.

A file contains commented out strings. For example:

```
abc
abc1
# def3
ghi5
qwe
```

I want to get all strings with a number in it, but not if this string prepended with "#". So in this example we should see

```
abc1
ghi5
```

The double grep solves the problem:

```
grep -vE "^#" file.txt | grep -E "[0-9]"
```

Now the question: Is there a way to do that in one run of grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be sure that the first character is a letter (you did not check for that either):

```
grep '^[^#].*[0-9]' file.txt
```

Comment: A corner case of single digit lines will not be caught.